# Time.Sleep() is freezing my pygame window and freezing my functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, pygame, sleep

So i got a big Problem and im researching it since 5 hours without getting anywhere, thats, why im asking here now. at the bottom you can see the Code, where i got my problem.
So what it basically does is: it opens an pygame window with 3 buttons: one with start, one with stop and one with quit

when you press start an loop should run, where it plays an sound every x seconds until you press the stop button.
the problem is, that the time.sleep() does freeze the whole window. and yes i researched a lot and i didnt came to a conclusion for myself... iam an beginner in python, im doing it for like 2 weeks. Also this is my first post at this Community, so sorry, if this post is different! :p

What i wanna have is, that while the Tonemaker Loop is running, the pygame window stays active and youre able to click the other buttons.

if you need any more informations just ask!
Thanks for your Help! Iam really thankful for every answer, because iam really stuck right now.

```
import pygame, threading
from pygame import *
import time


run = True
distance = int(input("What Distance you wanna Run? [Meters]:"))
timer = int(input("How fast do you wanna Run it? [Seconds]:"))  
frequence = int(input("The Tone should come every? [Meters]:")) 
# Ask all the needed informations and save them as Variables 

tonerepeats = distance / frequence
tonetimer = timer / tonerepeats  # Calculate the time the progam should wait inbetween the sounds
tonetimer = float(tonetimer)  # make the tonetimer an float (number)  important, otherwise sleep will give an error


pygame.init()
displaywidth = 800
displayheight = 800
black = (0, 0, 0)
grey = (30, 30 ,30)
white = (255, 255, 255)              #stuff for the pygame window
red = (200, 0, 0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
brightgreen = (0, 255, 0)
brightred = (255, 0, 0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displaywidth, displayheight))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tulsa Driller 1.0")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
tulsaimg = pygame.image.load("D:/python/tulsa.png")


def Tonemaker():                                                #the loop for the playsound function
    while run == True:  # as long as run is true do this
        pygame.mixer.init()  # needed line for playing an sound
        pygame.mixer.music.load("D:/python/sound.wav")  # load up the sound from libarys
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0)  # play the sound (0 = play 1 time) (1= play infinite)
        time.sleep(tonetimer)
          # After playing the sound wait x time till play it again
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # needed line for pygame to work
        clock.tick()  # needed line for pygame to work
        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():  # avoid errors with the playsound. "while the sound is playing do nothing"
            pygame.event.poll()
            clock.tick()





def tu(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(tulsaimg, (x,y))

x = (displaywidth*0.25 )
y = (displayheight*0.25 )

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):                 #function for the buttons
    mouse= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click= pygame.mouse.get_pressed()


    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action !=None:
            if action == "start": Tonemaker()           # if you press start it starts the loop
            elif action== "stop": run= False            #if you press stop the loop will stop
            elif action== "quit": quit()                #quit the program, when quit button is pressed


    smalltext = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smalltext)
    textRect.center = ((x + (w / 2)), (y + (h / 2)))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)



crashed = False

while not crashed:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True



    gameDisplay.fill(grey)
    tu(x, y)

    button("Start",150,650,100,50,green,brightgreen,"start")
    button("Stop", 350, 650, 100, 50, red, brightred,"stop")       #the 3 buttons
    button("Quit", 550, 650, 100, 50, red, brightred,"quit")

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(75)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You need to create a separate thread which will trigger the sound on and off.. Right now `Tonemaker` is running in the main thread. Now instead of blocking Tonemaker forever, you can use it to trigger another separate thread which handles the noise generation.

Comment: okay. i already tried sth. with thread.. but it doesnt really worked. how do i do an seperate thread to do this?

Comment: I don't think you need a separate thread. You already have a constant loop `while not crashed:...`. Just check the current time in that loop and call the function after 1 second. Repeat.

Comment: Let me share some sample code in a while.. Not specific to pygame, but just to help with you with the concept..

Comment: okay. that sounds good to me. how exactly do you mean it. so how do i do this with checking the current time?

Comment: alright thanks. so what i need here is an alternative to the time sleep command, which doesnt stop the code

Comment: [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) returns the time in seconds. Store that `last_time = time.time()`. Then in each iteration: `if time.time() - last_time >= 60: Tonemaker(); last_time = time.time()` Don't forget to remove the loop from `Tonemaker()`

Comment: awesome. ill try that @Johnny Mopp. that sound good to me. Ill tell you wether it worked or not after! :)

Comment: @Icaruz: You can check my answer. I believe that should give you an idea on how event handling should be done here.. And how a separate thread could come in handy.
A simpler solution is what you are discussing with Johnny. But I don't believe it's a very clean solution.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so i tried it. and it doess work. but not how i wants. what it does is, that if i press the button, the sound will play once. after it it just stops. there is no loop anymore :p

Comment: @Icaruz Ok. I will type up an answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it that incorporates the main loop you already have. It checks the time each iteration through the loop. If enough time has elapsed, it calls the `Tonemaker()` function. (Omitted irrelevant code).

```
import time

last_time = None
# Start the timer
def StartTone():
    last_time = time.time()
    ToneMaker()
# Stop the timer
def StopTone():
    last_time = None
# Play the sound
def Tonemaker():
    pygame.mixer.init()  # needed line for playing an sound
    pygame.mixer.music.load("D:/python/sound.wav")  # load up the sound from libarys
    pygame.mixer.music.play(0)  # play the sound (0 = play 1 time) (1= play infinite)


while not crashed:
    # Other stuff.....

    # Check elapsed time if timer is running
    if last_time != None:
        now = time.time()
        # Has time elapsed?
        if now - last_time >= tonetimer:
            Tonemaker()
            # Reset
            last_time = now
```

Comment: thanks. tried that way and that also worked! thank you all for youre help

Answer (score 1):

Just see if you can draw some inspiration from the below code snippet.
I'm not a pygame developer. But I believe in concept, it should be coded along the lines mentioned below.

```
import threading
import time

class SoundThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.quit = False
        self.event = threading.Event()  # Whenever this event is set, play sound
        self.event.clear()  # By default no sound should be played
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while not self.quit:
            eventSet = self.event.wait(timeout=1)
            if not eventSet:
                print("Skipping playing the sound")
                continue

            if self.quit:
                break
            # Play sound over here
            print("Play the sound")
            time.sleep(1)

    def begin(self):
        self.event.set()

    def halt(self):
        self.event.clear()

    def quit(self):
        self.quit = True


obj = SoundThread()
obj.start() # Launches a separate thread which can be controlled, based upon calls to begin, halt, and quit


# And add the below to wherever you have the action handlers.
if action == "start": obj.begin()
elif action== "stop": obj.halt()
elif action== "quit": obj.quit()
```

Comment: But you'll have to adapt it to your needs.. I don't think you can use it straighaway.

Comment: yeah. so i implemented your lines of code now and changed everythink and it worked thanks!!! what is this called exactly what you used there?? i wanna learn how to use it.  because for example i dont know what self.event.set() does exactly. is this part of threading?

Comment: Wow! congrats that you have it working.. 
You should read up concepts like mutex, events, and locks, and semaphores. 
Over here we have used the concept of events, which is a thread-safe way to set a flag. And also makes it possible to block on that event.
I'll appreciate if you can upvote my answer, since it worked for you! (https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Event_Objects_between_Threads.php)